# Python Different the datetime in a Struct Array

Tags: python, datetime, struct, for-in-loop, namedtuple

```
import struct
from collections import namedtuple

StructDeviceInfo = namedtuple('DeviceInfo', ['DeviceID', 'Capturing','Receiving','Socket','DateTime'])
DeviceInfoList = []

def threaded_function():
    while True:
        if any(x.Capturing == True and x.Datetime in DeviceInfoList different second > 5 for x in DeviceInfoList) : #here,how to do on here?
              print('True')
```

if the DeviceInfoList array inside the Capturing Value is TRUE and at the same time the Datetime are different with datetime.now are more than 5 second. then print true,how to do this?

p/s:the Capturing is TRUE and datetime is more than 5 seconds,must be same array index .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delta = datetime.datetime.now() - x.Datetime
if delta.total_seconds() > 5:
    # difference is greater than 5 seconds
```

Applied to your example, assuming that `x.Datetime` actually is a `datetime.datetime` object:

```
if any((
        x.Capturing == True and 
        (datetime.datetime.now() - x.Datetime).total_seconds() > 5
       ) for x in DeviceInfoList):
```

Comment: No,i prefer use in a sentences method like this e.g if any(x.Capturing == True for x in DeviceInfoList) and (x.Datetime in DeviceInfoList different second > 5)

Comment: @C.Y: That's trivial to apply, isn't it? I was just showing you the semantics of how to use `timedelta` objects.

Comment: and, where is your x come from?

Comment: @C.Y: The same place your `x` comes from.

Comment: sorry,answer can't make me understand how to implement in a sentences like this (x.Datetime in DeviceInfoList different second > 5)